# Want to prove that some $\mathbb R[x]$-Module has no basis

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

So here is my question,

Consider the $\mathbb R[X]$-module $\mathbb R[X,X^{-1}]$ i.e the $\mathbb R[x]$-module of all Laurent-Polynomials. I want to show that is module is not free i.e it has no basis.

I already feel I see the problem, since if one multiplies an element $p(x)\in\mathbb R[X^{-1}]$ with some element of the ring $\mathbb R[X]$ it is only possible to increase the degree of $p(x)$ but it is not possible to decrease it.

Moreover, I think if we I assume for contradiction that there exists a basis 0f $\mathbb R[X,X^{-1}]$ than it contains at least some reel constant $c$ as basis of $\mathbb R[X]\subset\mathbb R[X,X^{-1}]$. Then every basis has to be of the form $\{c,p_1,p_2,...\}$ where $p_i\in\mathbb R[X,X^{-1}]$ - $\mathbb R[X$] i.e is some polynomial of degree strictly less the zero. And this polynomials can not be linear independent since one can always increase the degree until it becomes again positv...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a base-free argumentation. Let us assume that $\mathbb{R}[X^{\pm 1}]$ is a free $\mathbb{R}[X]$-module then it is also projective. Let $g : \mathbb{R}[X,Y] \to \mathbb{R}[X^{\pm 1}]$ be the surjective $\mathbb{R}[X]$-algebra-homomorphism mapping $Y \mapsto X^{-1}$. Now by projectivity there is a $\mathbb{R}[X]$-module-homomorphism $f : \mathbb{R}[X^{\pm 1}] \to \mathbb{R}[X,Y]$ such that $g \circ f = id$. This leads easily to a contradiction: because of $X^n \cdot f(X^{-n}) = f(1) \in \mathbb{R}[X,Y]$ we see that $X^n$ divides $f(1)$ for all positive integers $n$ which forces $f(1)=0$. But then $X = gf(X) = X \cdot gf(1) = 0$.

Of course this argument still works if we replace $\mathbb{R}$ by any other (nonzero) commutative ring.

Answer (score 6):

Let $K$ be any field (nothing special about the real numbers here). Suppose $K[X,X^{-1}]$ were a free $K[X]$-module on some basis with cardinality $\gamma$ (finite or infinite). You already argued that $\gamma=1$ is not possible.

Now this would imply $K[X,X^{-1}]\otimes_{K[X]}K(X)$ is a $K(X)$-vector space of dimension$~\gamma$. But is is actually a $K(X)$-vector space of dimension$~1$, since any two elements of $K[X,X^{-1}]$ are obviously linearly dependent over$~K(X)$. Contradiction.

Comment: Nice use of scalar extension!

Comment: So, while it isn't free, it does have rank $1$.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $\mathcal{B}$ is a set of generators for $\mathbb{R}[X, X^{-1}]$ as an $\mathbb{R}[X]$-module. There must be terms of arbitrarily low lowest term, since - as you've correctly noted - multiplying elements of $\mathbb{R}[X, X^{-1}]$ by elements of $\mathbb{R}[X]$ can only increase the degree of the lowest term. So in particular, $|\mathcal{B}| = \infty$

But $1$ can be written as a finite $\mathbb{R}[X]$-linear sum of elements of $\mathcal{B}$, say $1 = f_1b_1 + ... + f_rb_r$. Let $b \in \mathcal{B}$ be such that $b \neq b_i$ for all $i$, and assume the lowest term of $b$ is degree $r < 0$. Then $bX^r \in \mathbb{R}[X]$ (and $bX^r \neq 0$).

But now $(f_1bX^r)b_1 + ... + (f_rbX^r) - bX^r$ is a non-trivial $\mathbb{R}[X]$-linear relation between elements of $\mathcal{B}$, so $\mathcal{B}$ cannot be a basis.

Comment: Thank you! This answer really helped me!

Answer (score 2):

*Observation*: Any two nonzero $\Bbb R[x]$ submodules of $\Bbb R[x,x^{-1}]$ intersect. If $M$ and $N$ are two such submodules and $a\in M$, $b\in N$ are nonzero elements. You can find powers of $x$ such that $x^ia\in \Bbb R[x]$ and $x^kb\in \Bbb R[x]$, and then you can find their gcd in $\Bbb R[x]$. That is, there exist $p,q$ such that $px^ia=qx^kb\in M\cap N$, showing the intersection is nonzero.

Using that observation, if $\Bbb R[x,x^{-1}]$ were free, it could not have more than one copy of $\Bbb R[x]$ in its decomposition. That would mean $\Bbb R[x,x^{-1}]$ is a cyclic $\Bbb R[x]$ module. But as you observed, no single element would suffice to generate all of $\Bbb R[x,x^{-1}]$, since the set of things a single element can generate has a definite lower bound on its degree.